# What is wrong with my .htaccess? 500 Internal server error

Tags: html, .htaccess

would you know what the issue is?

This works:

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.dsfds.lu
```

This doesn't work and return a "500 Internal server error":

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
ErrorDocument 404 /index.html
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.dsfds.lu
Redirect 301 /biographie-dfd-fdd/ biographie.html
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to redirect `/biographie-dfd-fdd/` to `biographie.html` in which case the space is needed

Comment: Can you check your Apache error.log file

Comment: That space is supposed to be there. Try using the full URL for the last part of the rule. I.E. `Redirect 301 /biographie-dfd-fdd/ http://example.com/biographie.html`

Comment: @CarlMarkham - I misread, thank you.

Comment: @JohnP no-one is perfect :)

Comment: @Greg: What is your Apache version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the full URL as the second argument

`Redirect 301 /biographie-dfd-fdd/ http://website.com/biographie.html`

Comment: The fact that one must use full URL as the second argument is **incorrect** It is effectively same as `Redirect 301 /biographie-dfd-fdd/ /biographie.html`

Comment: I tested it on my own local server. Using the relative URL produces a 500 error, using the absolute URL works fine.

Comment: I wouldn't have commented without testing it myself. I am using `Apache/2.2.25`

Comment: Fair enough :), I am using 2.2.22 under Windows, may be diffrent?

Comment: Yes older Apache versions behave differently. I think this behavior changed from `2.2.25` onwards.

Comment: I updated to apache 2.4.9 and can confirm you do not need the full URL, but do for versions earlier than 2.2.25, hats off to you sir

Comment: +1 for going through the pain of upgrading Apache and verifying our theory.